# Laravel does not send emails to other domains

Tags: laravel, email

I have a very strange problem, which I cannot solve.
I have configured my .env file as follows :

MAIL_MAILER `smtp`

MAIL_HOST=`mail.spaceweb.com.mx`

MAIL_PORT=`465`

MAIL_USERNAME=`noreply@spaceweb.com.mx`

MAIL_PASSWORD=`mypassword`

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=`ssl`

MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

Which more or less works for me, that is, if I send an email to contact@spaceweb.com.mx (same domain) it works correctly, but, if I send an email to micorreo@gmail.com it does not work. the mail arrives (another domain).

I have already tried several methods, but I can not solve or know what error happens, since it shows absolutely no errors.

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting account? Many providers of shared hosting space disable relay of email to external domain

Comment: I have a web hosting, could that be limiting the sending of emails?

Comment: But, if I send an email from webmail if it works, if it sends the emails

Comment: You need to contact support team of your web hosting provider and ask them to enable relay service for mail. Actually you can tell them what you have written here in your question and they can help you with setting up /enabling email relay service for your hosting account

Comment: Do you receive "Mail Delivery Failure" message?